# To store the employe name, their date of birth in table and display name with the current date

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am working on a Wordpress site where I want to display the name of those employees whose birthdays fall on the current date. 
Is there any wordpress plugin?

I have a table like this:

```
**Employee name | DOB**
Jon | 12-02-84
Ron | 5-04-83
Romeo | 22-08-85
Kishore | 24-09-84
Jimmy | 22-08-85
```

I want the result as below (suppose current date is 22-08-18)

```
Romeo | 
Jimmy
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, book, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make use of Advance Custom Fields. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

You can easily add custom fields to your post types and then query this from within your WordPress child theme files.

Please read the getting started guide for basic text input fields: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/text/

You can return values easily using their code docs:

```
<?php

 if(get_field('field_name'))
 {
   echo '<p>' . get_field('field_name') . '</p>';
 }

 ?>
```